# Why do I get error C2768 with using template type where I need the type as pointer sometimes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I have a class CMyObject that has some getter functions to access various members (e.g. of type CTheValueHolder) which in turn have a setter for a double value each. This call chain needs to be applied to all items of type CMyObject in a list, the accessed classes and their setter functions change randomly throughout the code. In order to keep the code short, I'd like to use a method where I can pass all, the getter function to the other object (CTheValueHolder) on the CMyObject instance, the function to be executed on that object and the value to be set.

The code looks as follows:

```
// header
class CMyService
{
    template <typename T> void ApplyToList(T* (CMyObject::*getMember)(), void (T::*memberFunction)(double), double iNewValue);
}

// implementation
template <typename T>
void CMyService::ApplyToList<T>(T* (CMyObject::*getMember)(), void (T::*memberFunction)(double), double iNewValue)
{
    std::list<CMyObject*>myList = GetList();
    std::list<CMyObject*>::iterator endIter = myList.end();
    for (std::list<CMyObject*>::iterator iter = myList.begin();  iter != endIter; iter++)
    {
        if (*iter)
        {
            (((*iter)->*getMember)->*memberFunction)(iNewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The CMyObject::*getMember might look as follows:

```
CTheValueHolder* CMyObject::GetTheValueHolder()
{
    return m_pTheValueHolder;
}
```

And CTheValueHolder might be defined as:

```
class CTheValueHolder
{
    // ....
    void SomeValueSetter(double fNewValue);
    // ....
}
```

So with that:

```
// call from within CMyService
void CMyService::SomeFunction()
{
    // ....
    double fSomeNewValue = 123.456;
    ApplyToList<CTheValueHolder>(&CMyObject::GetTheValueHolder, &CTheValueHolder::SomeValueSetter, fSomeNewValue);
    // ....
}
```

With that I get error C2768: 'CMyService::ApplyToList' : illegal use of explicit template arguments.
Any ideas why and how to make this work?
BTW: I'm currently stuck with VS2010, so I don't have the full-blown C++11 available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your out-of-line definition of a template function is wrong. If you explicitely specify template arguments after the *template name* (e.g., the `<T>` in `CMyService::ApplyToList<T>`), you're specifying a specialization. In this case a partial specialization, because the specialization still has template parameters. And you can't partially specialize functions.

```
template<class T> void Foo(); // declaration

// Don't do this:    
template<class T> void Foo<T>() { /* implementation */ }

// Do this:
template<class T> void Foo() { /* implementation */ }
//                       ^^^ Note the missing <T>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me one step closer. I get other errors now instead: C2220 "no 'object' file generated" and a warning C4100 for 'iNewValue', 'func2' and 'func' : unreferenced formal parameter.
It says as well: " see reference to function template instantiation 'void CMyObject::ApplyToList<CTheValueHolder>(T *(__thiscall CMyObject::* )(void),void (__thiscall CTheValueHolder::* )(double),double)' being compiled with [ T=CTheValueHolder ]"

Comment: where 'func2' = 'memberFunction' and  'func' = 'getMember'

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of
    (((*iter)->*getMember)->*memberFunction)(iNewValue);
I have to call:
    (((*iter)->*getMember)()->*memberFunction)(iNewValue);
(see the additional parenthesis after 'getMember'). Strange error message for that issue which was not clear to me at the beginning.